# How create own class helper in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I need to create own class with methods, that I want to call from diverse controllers.

What it should be: Library, Provider or Helper in Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Create folder `app/Helpers`

2: In `app/Providers` create new provider file `HelperServiceProvider.php`

3: In this file register all helpers classes you need

```
$this->app->bind('dateHelper', function()
{
    return new \App\Helpers\DateHelper;
});
... etc
```

4: In config/app.php add this new provider

```
'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
```

5: Then you need to create Facade to be available to use this helper in view. You find the info about how to create Facade on official [laravel.com](http://laravel.com) site

About the **providers**, you can read the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers)

**Source**: [Laravel Forums](http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1)

Comment: Can you explain how to use helper class in controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways

1. Static way

   - Create a folder your wish Utils or Helpers or Libraries.
   - Create a    Class (ex: Helper Class)
   - Added static methods here (ex: public    static common()).
   - Added namespace to the call.
   - Use the name    space and call the static function using(Helper::common)
2. Normal Class

   - Create class with name space.
   - Inject the Dependency of that class and use all function inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the simple steps below

- Step 1

  Create new helper file in `app/Helpers` directory
     Ex. I have created  the `DemoHelper.php` in directory `app/Helpers/DemoHelper.php`
- Step 2

  Add the entry of created `Helper(DemoHelper.php)` to composer.json file in autoload section

  ```
  "autoload": {
   "files": [
       "app/Helpers/Helper.php",
       "app/Helpers/DemoHelper.php"
   ]
  },
  ```
- Step 3

  Finaly, `composer dump-autoload` hit this command in terminal.